# pass exclamation mark as prop value in react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

Today I saw this line of code, I'm confused what it does, I know list is an array of object but what's that `!` for? How does it affect how I handle MyComponent component later?

```
<MyComponent list={data?.list!} />
```

Comment: It is called Optional Chaining. You can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining. The exclamation mark just specifies that you KNOW that the value exists, and so you are casting it to a value rather than undefined or null

Comment: @Norse isn't it a stupid move to make? the list is from api, what if the api return undefined?

Comment: Well, sometimes it is a stupid move, but other times you know that the value is there, and so you have to do it like that

Answer (score 0):

That a combination of:

- The optional chaining operator (`?.`, TypeScript and JavaScript), and
- The [non-`null` assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) (TypeScript) (really it's a non-*nullish* operator), which tells TypeScript that the resulting value is not either `null` or `undefined`.

The `data?.list` part gets the value of `data.list` if `data` is not `null` or `undefined`, or gets `undefined` if `data` *is* `null` or `undefined`. Then the `!` asserts to TypeScript that the result of `data?.list` is not `null` or `undefined` (more below).

Note that this code is, at best, slightly confused. It makes no sense to use optional chaining *and* a non-nullish assertion, since the only reason for using optional chaining is to handle the case where the base (`data`) may be `null` or `undefined` and use the value `undefined` (instead of looking up `.list`) if so. Going on to assert that it's non-nullish doesn't make sense. One or the other of those shouldn't be there.

I'm guessing the `!` is there because `MyComponent` doesn't allow its `list` prop to be `null` or `undefined`. If so, the code should be just:

```
<MyComponent list={data.list} />
```

...with appropriate logic beforehand to check that both `data` and `data.list` are not `null` or `undefined` or avoid rendering `MyComponent` at all if that's not true. For instance, perhaps:

```
{data?.list ? <MyComponent list={data.list} /> : null}
```

Comment: yes I rather do once `{data?.list ? <MyComponent list={data.list} /> : null}
` than many times inside the component, great insight TJ, thanks!